# Loading JNI libs- via Java threads or NDK pthreads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am loading many .so libraries into Android application. When I make JNI call, function in library.so runs an infinte loop, so it never returns to calling function.
Should I make JNI call from Java thread or should I load a function from pthreads in a library? Which is better?

Second question: how can I be sure that libraries are unloaded when user exits MainActivity?
Thanks.

Comment: let me clear up some misunderstanding: *libraries* are never running; there is no documented way to unload a library that was loaded from Java with `System.loadLibrary()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, basically what Alex said. It should not make much of a difference if you choose Java or pthreads.

For the second question, you should stash a pointer to the created libraries in your Java code. The easiest way is for your Jni call to return this pointer as a jlong. But since, your jni function never returns, you will have to directly set the value in the native code.

Checkout the implementation of the NativeHandle class here

http://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/26/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-part-2/

Then before the main activity exits (I presume in the onDestroy() method) make a call to a
jni function to stop libraries from running

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. I was asking how to be sure to unload libraries so when program crashes for example i know that libraries are not using memory..

Comment: Oh ok..the library is associated with the class that loads it (where you call system.loadLibrary()) I believe. As such, the only time when it is "unloaded" is when the loading class is garbage collecred. I don't believe there is a direct way to do this yourself.

Comment: edit: I found this http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll. But I'm not sure if that will work

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, there is probably going to be very little difference.  Your native thread will be attached to the JVM when you interact with Java.  Its going to depend on if you want to do your thread programming with pthreads or Java threads and which model makes the most sense for your particular application.

As far as the second question goes, you need to write some cleanup code to take care of that in a graceful way.